# Core Plot: Is it possible to set the axis text color depending on the background color?

Tags: colors, core-plot

I have different plots in my graph.

[image]

The plots' colors are immutable because they represent fix meanings. Is it possible to set the color of the axis labels depending on the background color? Alternatively, a text shadow or border would be sufficient too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not automatically, but you can create custom axis labels. The custom labels could use different text styles (which includes the color), shadows, fills, and/or border.

Comment: When I set the shadow with `CPTXYAxis *y = ...; y.labelShadow = ...`, the axis with its ticks gets the shadow, not the label (e.g. 75) itself. Can you give me a short example of how to add a shadow/border to a custom `CPTAxisLabel`?

Comment: All Core Plot layers have a `shadow` property. You can set the shadow directly on the text layer used to display the label text.